# Using CSS to cut off left and right side of an image while scaling a window

Tags: html, css

I currently have the following list of images:

```
<div id='images'>
        <img src="images/placeholders/ph.jpeg" alt="Content missing"/>
        <img src="images/placeholders/ph1.jpg" alt="Content missing"/>
        <img src="images/placeholders/ph2.jpg" alt="Content missing"/>
        <img src="images/placeholders/ph3.jpg" alt="Content missing"/>
    </div>
```

These images cycle and are placed ontop of eachother, fading in and out. The images have a fixed height, but a variable width. This width is variable on the left and righthand side.

Example bannerimage: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAOWg.jpg

What I'd like to have after scaling the browser window:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3Wp7.jpg

The height is fixed, both sides have been cut off by an equal amount during the browser window scaling. I hope someone could help me tackle this problem. I don't know what code to use to resize this the way I want it to.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use CSS `transform` to align the image, and add `overflow: hidden;` to the `#images`. Example:

```
#images {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#images img {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I wanted!